# Magento 2.4 is this possible bypass Elasticsearch?

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch, setup-di-compile

i have upgraded **magento 2.3.4 to 2.4.0** but when I run compile command, it's showing an error

[image]

Error:

```
  Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/8 [=================>----------]  62% 34 secs 340.0 MiB
In ClassReader.php line 43:
                                                                      
  Class Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper does not exist  
                                                                      

In ClassReader.php line 36:
                                                                      
  Class Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper does not exist
```

I want to use `mysql` instead of `elastic search`

Answer (score 1):

No, elasticsearch is prerequisite along with php7.4 for upgrading to Magento2.4. I've upgraded from 2.3.4 to 2.4.0 couple of days ago and it wouldn't let me upgrade without elasticsearch so I installed it and it upgraded smoothly.

Comment: I've done the same. Therefore I added the required rows into core_config_data and it seems to work (copied them from another 2.4 instance). However, I'm wondering if this is the usual approach when upgrading. Or is it required to add them with the CLI?

Comment: I did everything through CLI. Didn't change anything in core_config_data.

Comment: And how did you configure Elasticsearch in Magento? You could add that to your answer.

Comment: I just installed it from elastic search official website, link was given in magento official website. It was all running without any specific configurations in magento.

Comment: Just wondering who or what has inserted the `catalog/search/elasticsearch7_*` paths and values into core_config_data. These values must exist in the table for Magento 2.4, afaik.